# s2n library not linking with arm

Tags: linker

When I am trying to compile a package on arm64, It gives me the error
hidden symbol 'pthread_atfork' in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a (pthread_atfokr.oS) is referenced by DSO. fatal link failed:Bad value.

gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

I tried replacing -lpthread with -pthread in make file which of no use. I also tried to cross-compile the package and then run on arm which even resulted in the same error.I have been searching for a solution couldnot find any. The package works well with linux-x86. …

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

extracting pthread_atfork.o form libpthread.a and including the file pthrea_atfork.o in makefile made s2n work on ARM.